# @Formula pattern in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I was reading some interview questions on Hibernate and came across Hibernate derived properties. I was trying a simple example using @Formula annotations but it is not working. Can anyone please tell me what am i missing. Code snippets below

The output and the SQL queries are display at the end.

**Entity (Employee.java)**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7311873726885796936L;

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", length=31)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME", length=31)
private String lastName;

@Column(name="MONTHLY_SALARY")
private float monthlySalary;

@Formula("MONTHLY_SALARY*12")
    private float yearlySalary;

public Employee() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public float getMonthlySalary() {
    return monthlySalary;
}

public void setMonthlySalary(float monthlySalary) {
    this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
}

public float getYearlySalary() {
    return yearlySalary;
}
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">system</property>
    <property     name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name ="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="Employee"/>
   <!--   <mapping class="dto.UserDetailsEmbeddedId"/>-->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Tester class**
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    public class HibernateTest {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SessionFactory factory = (new     Configuration()).configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstName("Tarun");
    employee.setLastName("bhatt");
    employee.setMonthlySalary(34000);
    employee.setId(12);

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(employee);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("salary1 = "+employee.getYearlySalary());
    session.close();
    System.out.println("salary = "+employee.getYearlySalary());

}
```

}

**Output**
    salary1 = 0.0
    salary = 0.0

**Queries**
    Hibernate: create table EMPLOYEE (ID number(10,0) not null, FIRST_NAME varchar2(31 char), LAST_NAME varchar2(31 char), MONTHLY_SALARY float, primary key (ID))
    Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MONTHLY_SALARY, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

`@Formula` annotation is intended to be used during data-retrivial (`SELECT` in few words) so a read of and `Employee` looks as

`select ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MONTHLY_SALARY,MONTHLY_SALARY*12 as yearlySalary`

`@Formula` doesn't works for insertion or update